Java Stream create new Object List setting property null when it's the same comparing with previous item
We have a List of Objects based on Hibernate Envers, got from database:
List<SystemAudit> systemAuditList = new ArrayList<>();

        systemAuditList.add(new SystemAudit(0, "A0", "B0", "C0"));
        systemAuditList.add(new SystemAudit(1, "A0", "B1", "C0"));
        systemAuditList.add(new SystemAudit(2, "A0", "B1", "C0"));
        systemAuditList.add(new SystemAudit(3, "A1", "B1", "C0"));
        systemAuditList.add(new SystemAudit(4, "A1", "B2", "C0"));
        systemAuditList.add(new SystemAudit(5, "A1", "B2", "C0"));
        systemAuditList.add(new SystemAudit(6, "A2", "B2", "C0"));
        systemAuditList.add(new SystemAudit(7, "A2", "B3", "C1"));
        systemAuditList.add(new SystemAudit(8, "A2", "B3", "C1"));

We then filter the list to have only non-repeated items based on some properties:
var systemAuditListCorrectlyFiltered = SystemAudit.createRandomList().stream().collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                        Collectors.toCollection(() -> new TreeSet<>(Comparator
                                .comparing(SystemAudit::getDescriptionFieldA)
                                .thenComparing(SystemAudit::getDescriptionFieldB)
                                .thenComparing(SystemAudit::getDescriptionFieldC))),
                        ArrayList::new))
                .stream()
                .map(SystemAuditHelper::create)
                .sorted(Comparator.comparing(SystemAuditHelper::getId, Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.reverseOrder())))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

This works fine, our result is:
[{7, A2, B3, C1},
 {6, A2, B2, C0},
 {4, A1, B2, C0},
 {3, A1, B1, C0},
 {1, A0, B1, C0},
 {0, A0, B0, C0}]

But the result we want is a List of objects where the previous item retains only the properties that are different from the current item of the List.
The expected result is this:
[{7, null, B3,   C1  },
 {6, A2,   null, null},
 {4, null, B2,   null},
 {3, A1,   null, null},
 {1, null, B1,   null},
 {0, A0,   B0,   C0  }]

When the given property is equal, based on previous item from the same List, the new Object have it null.
We have a minimum reproducible code here:
https://onecompiler.com/java/4322zgsau

Since the properties of the previous SystemAuditHelper depend on the values of the current instance, you cannot achieve that within your first stream. Stream operations should be stateless and avoid stateful lambdas.
For a few references, check the paragraph Stateful Lambda Expression from the Java Tutorials:

Avoid using stateful lambda expressions as parameters in stream operations. A stateful lambda expression is one whose result depends on any state that might change during the execution of a pipeline.

And the Javadoc of the Stream class:

Most stream operations accept parameters that describe user-specified behavior, such as the lambda expression w -> w.getWeight() passed to mapToInt in the example above. To preserve correct behavior, these behavioral parameters:

must be non-interfering (they do not modify the stream source); and
in most cases must be stateless (their result should not depend on any state that might change during execution of the stream pipeline).


To obtain the desired output, you can simply iterate through the list starting from the second element, keep track of the previous and current element, and then create a new SystemAuditHelper to replace the previous one.
SystemAuditHelper prev;
SystemAuditHelper cur;
String fieldA, fieldB, fieldC;
for (int i = 1; i < systemAuditListCorrectlyFiltered.size(); i++) {
    prev = systemAuditListCorrectlyFiltered.get(i - 1);
    cur = systemAuditListCorrectlyFiltered.get(i);

    fieldA = prev.getDescriptionFieldA().equals(cur.getDescriptionFieldA()) ? null : prev.getDescriptionFieldA();
    fieldB = prev.getDescriptionFieldB().equals(cur.getDescriptionFieldB()) ? null : prev.getDescriptionFieldB();
    fieldC = prev.getDescriptionFieldC().equals(cur.getDescriptionFieldC()) ? null : prev.getDescriptionFieldC();

    systemAuditListCorrectlyFiltered.set(i - 1, new SystemAuditHelper(prev.getId(), fieldA, fieldB, fieldC));
}

If you really want to use java streams, you can achieve the same output with an IntStream.
IntStream.range(1, systemAuditListCorrectlyFiltered.size()).forEach(i -> {
    SystemAuditHelper prev = systemAuditListCorrectlyFiltered.get(i - 1);
    SystemAuditHelper cur = systemAuditListCorrectlyFiltered.get(i);

    String fieldA = prev.getDescriptionFieldA().equals(cur.getDescriptionFieldA()) ? null : prev.getDescriptionFieldA();
    String fieldB = prev.getDescriptionFieldB().equals(cur.getDescriptionFieldB()) ? null : prev.getDescriptionFieldB();
    String fieldC = prev.getDescriptionFieldC().equals(cur.getDescriptionFieldC()) ? null : prev.getDescriptionFieldC();

    systemAuditListCorrectlyFiltered.set(i - 1, new SystemAuditHelper(prev.getId(), fieldA, fieldB, fieldC));
});

Here is also a demo of your code at OneCompiler.

dani-vta thank you.
